# Unable to run linter-flake8 with atom editor

Tags: python, python-3.x, atom-editor, flake8, linter

I have the following error whenever I open a python file in Atom

```
/home/shihab/.atom/packages/linter/lib/linter-registry.js:154 [Linter] Error running Flake8 Error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/shihab/.conda/envs/paper2_py37/bin/flake8", line 11, in <module>
    load_entry_point('flake8==3.7.7', 'console_scripts', 'flake8')()
  File "/home/shihab/.conda/envs/paper2_py37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flake8/main/cli.py", line 18, in main
    app.run(argv)
  File "/home/shihab/.conda/envs/paper2_py37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flake8/main/application.py", line 394, in run
    self._run(argv)
  File "/home/shihab/.conda/envs/paper2_py37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flake8/main/application.py", line 381, in _run
    self.initialize(argv)
  File "/home/shihab/.conda/envs/paper2_py37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flake8/main/application.py", line 365, in initialize
    self.register_plugin_options()
  File "/home/shihab/.conda/envs/paper2_py37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flake8/main/application.py", line 206, in register_plugin_options
    self.check_plugins.register_options(self.option_manager)
  File "/home/shihab/.conda/envs/paper2_py37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flake8/plugins/manager.py", line 496, in register_options
    list(self.manager.map(register_and_enable))
  File "/home/shihab/.conda/envs/paper2_py37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flake8/plugins/manager.py", line 302, in map
    yield func(self.plugins[name], *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/shihab/.conda/envs/paper2_py37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flake8/plugins/manager.py", line 492, in register_and_enable
    call_register_options(plugin)
  File "/home/shihab/.conda/envs/paper2_py37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flake8/plugins/manager.py", line 404, in generated_function
    return method(optmanager, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/shihab/.conda/envs/paper2_py37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flake8/plugins/manager.py", line 221, in register_options
    add_options(optmanager)
  File "/home/shihab/.conda/envs/paper2_py37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flake8/_pyflakes.py", line 79, in add_options
    parser.config_options.extend(['builtins', 'doctests',
AttributeError: 'OptionManager' object has no attribute 'config_options'
    at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/home/shihab/.atom/packages/linter-flake8/node_modules/sb-exec/lib/index.js:56)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:182)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:961)
    at Socket.stream.socket.on (internal/child_process.js:380)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:182)
    at Pipe._handle.close [as _onclose] (net.js:596)
```

I have the following packages installed in Atom

1. linter 2.3.1
2. linter-flake8 2.4.0
3. linter-ui-default 1.8.0
4. python-autopep8 0.1.3
5. linter-matlab 1.2.0

Initially I found the error to saw that certain packages were not found, like mccabe and pycodestyle. I installed those packages through conda. But I'm unable to understand the current error.